# What is the difference between a variable and a symbol in LISP?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, symbols

In terms of scope? Actual implementation in memory? The syntax? For eg, if (let a 1) Is 'a' a variable or a symbol?

Comment: [clisp](http://clisp.sourceforge.net/) is a particular implementation of Common Lisp, and your question is about the language, so I took the liberty of changing your tags.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Jörg's answer points in the right direction. Let me add a bit to it.

I'll talk about Lisps that are similar to Common Lisp.

**Symbols as a data structure**

A symbol is a real data structure in Lisp. You can create symbols, you can use symbols, you can store symbols, you can pass symbols around and symbols can be part of larger data structures, for example lists of symbols. A symbol has a name, can have a value and can have a function value.

So you can take a symbol and set its value.

```
(setf (symbol-value 'foo) 42)
```

Usually one would write `(setq foo 42)`, or `(set 'foo 42)` or `(setf foo 42)`.

**Symbols in code denoting variables**

But!

```
(defun foo (a)
  (setq a 42))
```

or

```
(let ((a 10))
   (setq a 42))
```

In both forms above in the source code there are symbols and `a` is written like a symbol and using the function `READ` to read that source returns a symbol `a` in some list. But the `setq` operation does NOT set the symbol value of `a` to `42`. Here the `LET` and the `DEFUN` introduce a *VARIABLE* `a` that we write with a symbol. Thus the `SETQ` operation then sets the variable value to `42`.

**Lexical binding**

So, if we look at:

```
(defvar foo nil)

(defun bar (baz)
  (setq foo 3)
  (setq baz 3))
```

We introduce a global variable `FOO`.

In bar the first `SETQ` sets the symbol value of the global variable `FOO`. The second `SETQ` sets the local variable `BAZ` to `3`. In both case we use the same `SETQ` and we write the variable as a symbol, but in the first case the `FOO` donates a global variable and those store values in the symbol value. In the second case `BAZ` denotes a local variable and how the value gets stored, we don't know. All we can do is to access the variable to get its value. In Common Lisp there is no way to take a symbol `BAZ` and get the local variable value. We don't have access to the local variable bindings and their values using symbols. That's a part of how lexical binding of local variables work in Common Lisp.

This leads for example to the observation, that in compiled code with no debugging information recorded, the symbol `BAZ` is gone. It can be a register in your processor or implemented some other way. The symbol `FOO` is still there, because we use it as a global variable.

**Various uses of symbols**

A symbol is a data type, a data structure in Lisp.

A variable is a conceptual thing. Global variables are based on symbols. Local lexical variables not.

In source code we write all kinds of names for functions, classes and variables using symbols.

There is some conceptual overlap:

```
(defun foo (bar) (setq bar 'baz))
```

In the above SOURCE code, `defun`, `foo`, `bar`, `setq` and `baz` are all symbols.

`DEFUN` is a symbol providing a macro.
`FOO` is a symbol providing a function.
`SETQ` is a symbol providing a special operator. 
`BAZ` is a symbol used as data. Thus the quote before `BAZ`.
`BAR` is a variable. In compiled code its symbol is no longer needed.

Answer (score 15):

Quoting from the [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/):

> [**symbol**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#symbol) *n.* an [*object*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_o.htm#object) of [*type*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_t.htm#type) [symbol](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_symbol.htm#symbol).
>
> [**variable**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_v.htm#variable) *n.* a [*binding*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_b.htm#binding) in the “variable” [*namespace*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_n.htm#namespace).
>
> [**binding**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_b.htm#binding) *n.* an association between a [*name*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_n.htm#name) and that which the *name* denotes. (…)

Explanation time.

What Lisp calls **symbols** is fairly close to what many languages call variables. In a first approximation, symbols have values; when you evaluate the expression `x`, the value of the expression is the value of the symbol `x`; when you write `(setq x 3)`, you assign a new value to `x`. In Lisp terminology, `(setq x 3)` binds the value 3 to the symbol `x`.

A feature of Lisp that most languages don't have is that **symbols are ordinary objects** (symbols are first-class objects, in programming language terminology). When you write `(setq x y)`, the value of `x` becomes whatever the value of `y` was at the time of the assignment. But you can write `(setq x 'y)`, in which case the value of `x` is the symbol `y`.

Conceptually speaking, there is an [environment](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_e.htm#environment) which is an association table from symbols to values. Evaluating a symbol means looking it up in the current environment. (Environments are first-class objects too, but this is beyond the scope of this answer.) A **binding** refers to a particular entry in an environment. However, there's an additional complication.

Most Lisp dialects have multiple namespaces, at least a namespace of variables and a namespace of functions. An environment can in fact contain multiple entries for one symbol, one entry for each namespace. A variable, strictly speaking, is an entry in an environment in the **namespace of variables**. In everyday Lisp terminology, a symbol is often referred to as a variable when its binding as a variable is what you're interested in.

For example, in `(setq a 1)` or `(let ((a 1)) ...)`, `a` is a symbol. But since the constructs act on the variable binding for the symbol `a`, it's common to refer to `a` as a variable in this context.

On the other hand, in `(defun a (...) ...)` or `(flet ((a (x) ...)) ...)`, `a` is a also symbol, but these constructs act on its function binding, so `a` would not be considered a variable.

In most cases, when a symbol appears unquoted in an expression, it is evaluated by looking up its variable binding. The main exception is that in a function call `(foo arg1 arg2 ...)`, the function binding for `foo` is used. The value of a quoted symbol `'x` or `(quote x)` is itself, as with any quoted expression. Of course, there are plenty of special forms where you don't need to quote a symbol, including `setq`, `let`, `flet`, `defun`, etc.

Answer (score 11):

A *symbol* is a name for a thing. A *variable* is a mutable pointer to a mutable storage location.

In the code snippet you showed, both `let` and `a` are symbols. Within the scope of the `let` block, the symbol `a` denotes a variable which is currently bound to the value `1`.

But the name of the thing is not the thing itself. The symbol `a` is not a variable. It is a *name* for a variable. But *only* in this specific context. In a different context, the name `a` can refer to a completely different thing.

Example: the symbol `jaguar` may, depending on context, denote

- [OSX 10.2](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_v10.2)
- [a gaming console](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Atari_Jaguar)
- [a car manufacturer](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Jaguar_Cars)
- [a ground attack military jet airplane](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/SEPECAT_Jaguar)
- [another military jet airplane](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/XF10F_Jaguar)
- [a supercomputer](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Jaguar_(computer))
- [an electric guitar](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Fender_Jaguar)
- and [a whole lot of other things](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Jaguar_(disambiguation))
- oh, did I [forget something?](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Jaguar)

Comment: +1 for mentioning symbols meaning different things in different contexts. This really helps when trying to understand the difference between **x** and **#'x** and **'x**.

Comment: excellant answer. thank you

Answer (score 4):

Lisp uses *environments* which are similar to maps (key -> value) but with extra built-in mechanisms for chaining environments and controlling bindings.

Now, *symbols* are pretty much, *keys* (except special form symbols), and point to a value,
ie *function*, *integer*, *list*, etc.
Since Common Lisp gives you a way to alter the values, i.e. with `setq`, symbols in some contexts
(your example) are also *variables*.

Answer (score 4):

A symbol is a Lisp data object.  A Lisp "form" means a Lisp object that is intended to be evaluated.  When a symbol itself is used as a Lisp form, i.e. when you evaluate a symbol, the result is a value that is associated with that symbol.  The way values are associated with symbols is a deep part of the Lisp langauge.  Whether the symbol has been declared to be "special" or not greatly changes the way evaluation works.

Lexical values are denoted by symbols, but you can't manipulate those symbols as objects yourself.  In my opinion, explaining anything in Lisp in terms of "pointers" or "locations" is not the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a side note to the above answers:

Newcomers to Lisp often are not sure exactly what symbols are for, besides being the names of variables.  I think the best answer is that they are like enumeration constants, except that you don't have to declare them before using them.  Of course, as others have explained, they are also objects.  (This shouldn't seem strange to users of Java, in which enumeration constants are objects too.)

Comment: Interesting answer

Answer (score 1):

Symbol and variable are 2 different things.
Like in mathematic symbol is a value. And variable have the same meaning than in mathematic.

But your confusion came from the fact that symbol are the meta representation of a variable.

That is if you do

```
(setq a 42)
```

You just define a variable a. Incidentally the way common lisp store it is throw the **structure of a symbol**.

In common lips symbol is a structure withe different property. Each one can be access with function like `symbol-name`, `symbol-function`...

In the case of variable you can access his value via s`symbol-value`

```
? (symbol-value 'a)
42
```

This is not the common case of getting the value of a.

```
? a
42
```

Note that symbols are self evaluating that mean that if you ask a symbol you get the symbol not the `symbol-value`

```
? 'a
A
```