# How to find variable in package using string and change it?

Tags: package, lisp, common-lisp

I have package with some variables:

```
(in-package #:pack)

(defparameter *a* "foo")
(defparameter *b* "bar")
```

Variables `*a*` and `*b*` are exported.

My goal is change this variables using strings (`"*a*"` and `"*b*"`)

I can find these variables with `intern` function

```
(symbol-value (intern (string-upcase "*a*") :pack)) ;; return *a* symbol
(symbol-name (intern (string-upcase "*a*") :pack))  ;; return "foo"
```

But if I trying to change symbol with

```
(setf (symbol-name (intern (string-upcase "*a*") :pack)) "baz")
```

I've got an error:

```
The function (COMMON-LISP:SETF COMMON-LISP:SYMBOL-NAME) is undefined.
[Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

How can I change these variables?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? To change the value, you need to set the `SYMBOL-VALUE` rather than `SYMBOL-NAME` (which you could do by using `SET` instead of `SETF` too). `FIND-SYMBOL` might also be better than `INTERN`, if you don't want to create new symbols in the package.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks.

I need to change sdl animation with osc commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in a comment @jkiiski, there is function in common lisp used to find symbols in a package:

[find_symbol:](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_s.htm)

Function FIND-SYMBOL

Syntax:

find-symbol string &optional package => symbol, status

Then the other important thing is take a look at the answer here for [understanding the difference between variables and symbols in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590221/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-a-symbol-in-lisp).

And the function set, setq and setf from common [lisp hypersec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/X_Alph_S.htm)

> set changes the contents of the value cell of symbol to the given
>   value.
>
> setq(setq var1 form1 var2 form2 ...) is the simple variable assignment
>   statement of Lisp. First form1 is evaluated and the result is stored
>   in the variable var1, then form2 is evaluated and the result stored in
>   var2, and so forth. setq may be used for assignment of both lexical
>   and dynamic variables.
>
> (setf place newvalue) expands into an update form that stores the
>   result of evaluating newvalue into the location referred to by place.
>   Some place forms involve uses of accessors that take optional
>   arguments. Whether those optional arguments are permitted by setf, or
>   what their use is, is up to the setf expander function and is not
>   under the control of setf. The documentation for any function that
>   accepts &optional, &rest, or ..... key arguments and that claims to be
>   usable with setf must specify how those arguments are treated.

So joining all this things we can have this code:

```
(defpackage :pack
  (:use :cl) ;; You must import this line in order to use functions from cl package like setf
  (:export :*a*
           :*b*))

(in-package :pack)

(defparameter *a* "foo")
(defparameter *b* "bar")
```

Now lets explore the variables

```
CL-USER> pack:*a*
"foo"
CL-USER> pack:*b*
"bar"
```

Then we can find the symbol *a* (note that common lisp is case insensitive if you don't use || for naming symbols)

```
CL-USER> (find-symbol "*A*" :pack)
PACK:*A*
:EXTERNAL
```

So here, there is nothing unexpected exists symbol *a* and it is external to the package pack

then let's change the value wit set we can directly change the value but with setf we need a place, a pointer in the case of common lisp a symbol have different pointers in this case the important for us is symbol-value. so for changing that we can proceed as follow:

```
CL-USER> (set (find-symbol "*A*" :pack) "baz")
"baz"
CL-USER> pack:*a*
"baz"
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-value (find-symbol "*A*" :pack)) "buzz" )
"buzz"
CL-USER> pack:*a*
"buzz"
```

Hope this helps.